# Can I claim my luggage if I am forced to stop after only the first leg of my journey

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage

I booked a ticket from Toronto to Rome with Air Canada. The flight has one stop, in Frankfurt. For personal reasons I need to get off in Frankfurt (it was not a cheaper ticket, I didn't know that when I was booking my ticket). Note that the stop is a bit less than 2 hours and that the second leg is operated by Lufthansa.

I am travelling with a checked-in luggage. What's the best way to get my registered luggage in Frankfurt? Should I inform the airline before I board in Toronto? Should I tell a stewardess before landing at Frankfurt? Or is it better to say that after I land?

Also note that I actually live in Germany. I don't need a visa etc.

Comment: @pnuts I do plan to travel to Rome later but I do not know right now when and it doesn't really matter right now. So it would be nice if I can use it later but in practice I don't care.

Comment: Don't be shy about your personal reasons. They may be just the thing to convince an airline staff to accommodate your needs.

Comment: A) if this is a return ticket say good bye to your return segment B) if you actually live in Germany expect Air Canada to at least think (but perhaps not say, they are polite) "this guy is trying to pull off a hidden city ticketing, no way". You might *state* some reasons but how can Air Canada know you are speaking the truth?

Comment: Well, the ticket to Frankfurt was cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

You can call in advance and ask your booking be changed (for a fee and potential fare difference) or you can ask at check-in that your booking be changed (again for fee and fare difference).  Be right up front about it, with your reasons why you need to change, airline employees are not heartless beings. Don't try and change once you are airborne or upon arrival at Frankfurt.

But keep in mind this change will effect any other flights on the ticket (if you are just starting a round trip, not an issue if you are homeward bound).

Answer (score 0):

When you initially check your luggage, you can always request that it gets *short-checked* to Frankfurt only. That should be no problem.

Note though - as others stated - by walking out in Frankfurt, you are *losing* all remaining segments on the complete round-trip ticket. *Losing* as in 'non-refundable, non-re-whatever, *gone-gone*'.

Comment: > you can always request that it gets short-checked to Frankfurt only. - No way. Absolutely no way. A lot of airlines will refuse or charge exorbitant fees for this to avoid hidden city ticketing. Do a search on short checking on this site.

Answer (score -2):

Once in Frankfurt you should inform the airline that you are not going to take your connection and they must get your bags off the plane for security reasons.

Comment: This idea is very likely to delay the Rome flight - try to find one suitcase among the bags that are going on to Rome.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74488/is-it-possible-to-purposefully-miss-a-flight-to-force-a-short-check